# gitconfig aliasing using !source doesn't work (zsh)

Tags: git, alias, git-config

I have a gitconfig like this:

```
[alias]
l = "!source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log"
```

When I run it I get this:

```
[desktop] git l
source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log: 1: source: not found
error: cannot run source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'l': 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log': No such file or directory
```

When I add any other shell builtins to test, they run fine:

```
[alias]
l = "!echo running from the builtin"

[desktop] git l
running from the builtin
```

Any idea why the source command can't be found from git?  I am running zsh, but changing to bash didn't seem to make a difference:

```
[desktop] bash
[desktop] git l
source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log: 1: source: not found
error: cannot run source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'l': 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log': No such file or directory
```

Comment: sorry if question is silly but why do you need to prepend `source`?

Comment: This is actually an example from Gary Bernhardt's gitconfig, and the .githelpers he has a function called pretty_git_log().  I assumed the source call would make the pretty_git_log function available as a command on the command line, but not totally sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The failure comes from the fact that the `!<command>` construct tries to find a program by that name to run. There is a `/bin/echo` program (which is different from your shell's built in `echo`, but that's a different story), but there is not a `/bin/source` (or `/usr/bin` or any other place). By nature of what `source` does, it cannot be a separate program.

Try this instead:

```
[alias]
l = "!sh -c 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log'"
```

Change `sh` to `bash` (or whatever) as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I actually tried this with other builtins that didn't have a binary version (I thought anyways) and they also worked, but in any case, your example worked!  Thanks.

Comment: l = "!bash -c 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log'" worked for me, thanks!