# How do a source a file via symlink in git alias?

Tags: git, bash, symlink

I have a file that I want to source for a git alias. However, git doesn't seem to follow symlinks. When using the following config (where ~/.githelpers is a symlink):

```
# .gitconfig
[alias]
  test = "!source ~/.githelpers && my_function"
...

# in the terminal I get
> git test
-> source ~/.githelpers: 1: source ~/.githelpers: source: not found
-> fatal: While expanding alias 'test': 'source ~/.githelpers': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

using

```
[alias]
  test = "!source ~/.githelpers && my_function"
```

results in

```
Using source `readlink ~/.githelpers`: 1: source `readlink ~/.githelpers`: source: not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'test': 'source `readlink ~/.githelpers`': No such file or directory
```

Maybe it's not a symlink issue after all.

Comment: Try using `. ~/.githelpers` instead. `source` is a bashism and it looks like its executing it in a non-bash shell.

Comment: @jordanm +1, can you make it an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

`source` is not a program that `git` can locate to run. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498901/gitconfig-aliasing-using-source-doesnt-work-zsh) for an alternate.